# How to get/read other website file structure

Tags: javascript

I want to know how I can read other websites file structure.

For example if the website is : www.test.com, I want to retrieve how many files they have on their server and which ones are html and which is css. I don't want to edit them or anything just count.

example:
root folder > index.html , about.html    (2 html files)
root folder > scripts > main.js          (1 javascript)

The folder names may vary so it should search entire structure.

I have tried google but I get results that want's to access the actual file content that I do not want.

I am using javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't really be done.

You don't know that a file exists on some other server unless someone links to it. I have a picture of a giraffe on my site, but unless I tell you where it is you won't be able to find it (or count it).

That said, if you are using Node.js, you can use something like the [crawler](https://www.npmjs.org/package/crawler) library to visit every public page of a site and open every link, then count the amount of files you see.

Comment: That is what I needed. I just wanted to see all the public files of website. I will look at that crawler documentation. Thanks